# Four classes in one tabber in Android?

Tags: android, tabactivity

I want to do as UITabBarController does in iPhone, 
I have four classes and I want to work them in one tabber

as I click first tab, first class should show
as I click second tab, second class should show
as I click third tab, third class should show
as I click fouth tab, fourth class should show

What is best and easy way to manipulate with such conditions,
I am new to Android developement and this is my first app
if you are not clear with question, may ask again ...

Comment: "as I click first tab, first class should show as I click second tab, second class shoule show as I click second tab, second class shoule show as I click second tab, second class shoule show" - this is clear for sure as you've repeated it 3 times

Comment: Now read the question, I did editing

Answer (score 0):

The android dev site has exactly an example you're looking for. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

There are code examples. You'll need to make a tab layout xml file, edit the main.xml and then in the java code, for each tab you'll have something like this

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
      .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Java code for implementing tab bar in android

```
           tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab

    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");
    TabSpec fourthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid4");
    TabSpec fifthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid5");

    viewCache[0] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, null);
    viewCache[1] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, null);
    viewCache[2] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, null);
    viewCache[3] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, null);
    viewCache[4] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, null);

    firstTabSpec.setIndicator(viewCache[0]);
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator(viewCache[1]);
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator(viewCache[2]);
    fourthTabSpec.setIndicator(viewCache[3]);
    fifthTabSpec.setIndicator(viewCache[4]);

    firstTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, HomeTabActivityGroup.class));
    secondTabSpec
            .setContent(new Intent(this,   ProfileTabActivityGroup.class));
    thirdTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,
            NotificationTabActivityGroup.class));
    fourthTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,
            FavoritesTabActivityGroup.class));
    fifthTabSpec
            .setContent(new Intent(this, MoreTabActivityGroupNew.class));

    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(fourthTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(fifthTabSpec);
```

//*************************************************************************
          This is the xml coed for Tab bar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        tabStripEnabled = "false"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

//*************************************************************************
This is the xml coed for Tab1.xml for tab layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```